# How to make gallery-wrap with imagemgick or css?

Tags: html, css, imagemagick

Gallery wrap is process (used in framing & canvas stretching) which paste some part of the image on frame border, shown in the image below, you can see some parts of image are stretched to 1.5" thick section of the frame.

[image]

Now the question is that can we avail this using imagemagick or css.

Comment: Some ideas and links here https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#box3d

Comment: If on Linux or Mac OSX, see http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/3Dcover/index.php